# Difference between process.env["APP_PATH"] and process.env.APP_PATH

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, nestjs

I'm currently working on a nestjs project. and the developer of the project has used a .env file to keep the app path and some other required information (i don't have access to this file) in the code he has accessed the attributes of .env file in two different ways.

**first way**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.enableCors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000' });
  }
```

**second way**

```
 PDFModule.register({
      isGlobal: true,
      view: {
        root: join(process.env["APP_PATH"], 'resources/pdf'),
        engine: 'mustache',
      },
    }),
```

i want to what is different in using `process.env.NODE_ENV` and `process.env["APP_PATH"]` to access attributes in .env file? and how can i specify app path correctly in .env file.

Comment: `NODE_ENV` env. var is commonly `"development"` or `"production"`. I don't know about `APP_PATH`

Comment: @MicaelLevi yeah i know what value to assign it but what i'm asking is the difference between two access methods with . and []

Comment: The `[]` you are mentioning is the [Computed Property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) was introduced in  ECMAScript 2015. So there are 2 ways to access an object property - using `[]` and `.`. Afaik there is no difference

Comment: oh, then you could ask _what's the difference between `process.env["NODE_ENV"]` vs `process.env.NODE_ENV`_ ;).  Look at @kiranvj response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yeah i know what value to assign it but what i'm asking is the
> difference between two access methods with . and []

The `[]` you are mentioning is the [Computed Property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) was introduced in ECMAScript 2015. So there are 2 ways to access an object property - using `[]` and `.`

Also `[]` is handy when you don't know the environment variable `NODE_ENV` but its available in another variable.

Example  `let myEnvVariable = "NODE_ENV";`

In this case `process.env[myEnvVariable]`  is same as  `process.env.NODE_ENV` or `process.env["NODE_ENV"]`